# Nesting routes in React using HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm creating dashboard/admin control panel application in React  and I'm not sure how to handle component rendering correctly.
So at first my main App component looks like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
 <div className="main--container">
  <HashRouter>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login"/>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
  </HashRouter>
 </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

And it works great, but after user is logged in I'm redirecting him to `/dashboard` where I want to nest other routes like `/dashboard/foo` or `/dashboard/goo/`

My dashboard component:

```
<React.Fragment>
 <Sidebar/>
  <div className="main--dashboard">
      Here I want to render other components.         
  </div>
 <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
</React.Fragment>
```

Where `<Sidebar/>` is going to control which component should render next to the sidebar.
So my question is how to swtich routes and render appropriate components without affecting(Sidebar should be always present) `<Sidebar/>` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

> Dashboard.js

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <Sidebar>
      <Login />  //as well <Register /> in Register.js
    </Sidebar>
  </React.Fragment>
```

> Login.js

```
<div className="main--dashboard">
    // Here you can render your components And also <Sidebar> remains as it is while redirects this.
</div>
<button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
```